# Homotopically equivalence of two simple connected covering spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Good afternoon,

Please, I would like you to help me with a solution to this problem, if you want:

Let $ \widetilde{X} $ and $ \widetilde{Y} $ be two simply connected covering spaces for linearly connected and locally connected spaces $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Show that if $ X\simeq Y $ (homotopically equivalent), then $ \widetilde{X}\simeq\widetilde{Y}$.

I tried to start from the definition of the concept of covered space and from the definition of the homotopically equivalence between two spaces. Along with these, I read the definition of the concept of lift maps, with the results of existence and uniqueness, but, unfortunately, I fail to build the connection between all of  these.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you for your time.